# How to find a column with all values in a list as column records when the list is passed as a dynamic query argument

Tags: mysql, spring, querydsl

The member_language table contains the following columns
[id, member_id, language_category]

Here is an example table data structure (member_id, language_category)

```
1-KR
1-EN
1-CN
1-JP
2-EN
2-CN
2-JP
```

Here's the query result I want

For example, if the list of categories goes into List.of(EN, CN, JP), I need to get the member_id that has all of these categories applied as LIst
In the data above, we should get 1 and 2 as the result.

Then List.of(KR, EN, CN, JP) should only return 1.
I want this structure, but I'm not sure how to write the query, can anyone help?

```java
final List<Long> containsLanguageMenteeIds = query
        .selectDistinct(availableLanguage.member.id)
        .from(availableLanguage)
        .where(filteringLanguage(condition.language()))
        .orderBy(availableLanguage.member.id.desc())
        .fetch();

private Predicate filteringLanguage(final SearchMenteeCondition.LanguageCondition language) {
    if (language.contains()) {
        return availableLanguage.language.category.in(language.values());
//            final BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
//            for (final Language.Category category : language.values()) {
//                builder.or(availableLanguage.language.category.eq(category));
//            }
//            return builder;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I wrote the above query with QueryDsl, but this Inquery results in member_id even if one of the elements inside is included, which is not the answer I want.

Comment: You may, for example, 1) select rows by "language_category is present in the categories list" 2) group by member_id and count the amount of rows 3) select only those member_id for which the amount is equal to the categories list length.